# SimpleFSDirectory not working in python lucene

Tags: python, indexing, lucene

```
import sys, os
import lucene

from java.io import File
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard import StandardAnalyzer
from org.apache.lucene.index import DirectoryReader
from org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic import QueryParser
from org.apache.lucene.document import Document, Field
from org.apache.lucene.index import IndexWriter, IndexWriterConfig
from org.apache.lucene.store import SimpleFSDirectory
from org.apache.lucene.util import Version


def index(start, no, dom): 
    lucene.initVM()
    # join base dir and index dir
    path = raw_input("Path for index: ")
    index_path = File(path)
    directory = SimpleFSDirectory(index_path) # the index
```

I keep having errors with the SimpleFSDirectory, even when I tried other things like directory = SimpleFSDirectory(File(os.path.abspath("paths")))

InvalidArgsError: (, '**init**', (,))

Answer (score 0):

As of 5.0, the SimpleFSDirectory ctor no longer takes a `File` argument, it takes a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html?is-external=true). You can convert to a Path, with `File.toPath()`.

Also, I would recommend you use [`FSDirectory.open`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-), instead. FSDirectory.open allows lucene to try to choose the best Directory implementation for the current environment, which will generally perform better than a SimpleFSDirectory.

So, something like:

```
index_path = File(path).toPath()
directory = FSDirectory.open(index_path)
```